# Rx .net Subscribe() and EventPattern oddity

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm using Rx in conjunction with a third-party API that uses the `EventPattern`.  In this API you register your event handlers on the object and then invoke a method, `StartWatching()`, on the object that starts the events to begin triggering.  I am using `Observable.FromEventPattern` to bridge the API in the Rx world but I am running into very odd problems where subscriptions will only work if they are called right by the invocation of `StartWatching()`.  Below is a *reduced* case of what I am seeing.

This works:

```
foreach (var iq in interactionQueues)
        {
            Observable.FromEventPattern(iq, "TheEvent")
                .Subscribe(e => Log.Info("I got called!"), 
                       e => Log.Info("Error!", e),
                       () => Console.WriteLine("Seq completed!"));

            iq.StartWatching();
        }
```

If I call the `Subscribe()` and `StartWatching()` in different loops it stops working:

```
foreach (var iq in interactionQueues)
            Observable.FromEventPattern(iq, "TheEvent")
                .Subscribe(e => Log.Info("I got called!"), 
                       e => Log.Info("Error!", e),
                       () => Console.WriteLine("Seq completed!"));
foreach (var iq in interactionQueues)
           iq.StartWatching();
```

My only thought as to why this may happen is that the Observing or Subscribing is happening on the wrong thread.  I have tried using `Scheduler.CurrentThread` and `Scheduler.Immediate` with `SubscribeOn` and `ObserveOn` but that didn't help.  Any other  ideas?  Should I try a different `Scheduler` or is that a red herring?

Comment: Maybe interactionQueues.Next() generates new object on every call? If that's the case you call `StartWatching` on the wrong object.

Comment: Doh, you are right @Lazin!  Calling `ToArray()` on my collection to force realization fixed the problems.  That makes a lot more sense that odd subscription problems. :)  Yay, Occam's Razor. :)  If you want to make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Whatever the case, separation of the subscription(Observable.Subscribe) and subscription initialization(StartWatching) is not a good idea. You need to create single `cold` observable, that will call internally `StartWatching` and ref-count subscribers. I think Paul's solution will solve this problem nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's wrap this in a more friendly method:

```
public static TheEventArgs WatchEvent(this InteractionQueue this)
{
    var ret = Observable.Create<TheEventArgs>(subj => {
        // This entire block gets called every time someone calls Subscribe
        var disp = new CompositeDisposable();

        // Subscribe to the event
        disp.Add(Observable.FromEventPattern(iq, "TheEvent").Subscribe(subj));

        // Stop watching when we're done
        disp.Add(Disposable.Create(() => iq.StopWatching());

        iq.StartWatching();

        // This is what to Dispose on Unsubscribe
        return disp;
    });

    // When > 1 person Subscribes, only call the block above (i.e. StartWatching) once
    return ret.Multicast(new Subject<TheEventArgs>()).RefCount();
}
```

Comment: Very nice, I was planning on wrapping up the resource management better and this looks like a great solution. Thanks!  The only thing I don't understand is the use of `Multicast(...)` instead of just `Publish().RefCount()`.  Will `Publish()` not do the same thing?  Or is it that you just want to avoid having to call `Connect()`?

Comment: You're totally right, `Publish().RefCount()` is the same, I'm just used to always using Multicast